# Webpack may need appropriate loaders to handle file. Loaders not loading CSS from imports

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, webpack-dev-server, css-loader

Having trouble with my webpack config file not loading the CSS from my imported files. I have looked at several issues that people have had online updated the test regex for the loaders and added a file loader as well as a url loader but am still having the same problem. It's as though Webpack (v3) doesn't know where or how to load the css from any of my imported files.  I should also note that I originally created this app using create-react-app and then removed the node_modules and setup my own custom webpack config and babel files.

The Error message I'm getting is:-

[image: webpack-dev-server error message]

My Package JSON:- 
Basics are I have installed all of the css, sass and postcss, loaders I can after checking several issues online. Its a react 16 app with react router V4.

```
      "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.31.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^2.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^4.2.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "font-awesome-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "transfer-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  },
```

My webpack config file.

```
var cssName = 'index.css';

const extractText =  new extractTextPlugin(cssName);


module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.css', './src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path:  path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    extractText,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,  
      exclude: /node_modules/,  
      loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },{ 
      test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg|jpeg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
    },{
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: 'style!css!less'
    },{ 
      test: /\.jsx?$/, 
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
        presets:[ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-2' ]
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

My babelrc File.

/* 
    ./.babelrc
*/

```
{
    "presets": ["react", ["es2015", { modules: false }]],
    "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }],
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `css-loader` config excludes `node_modules`, which `font_awesome.css` is in:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,  
  exclude: /node_modules/,  
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

You can use an `include` as a whitelist instead:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,  
  include: [ 
    path.resolve(__dirname, "your_src"),  
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/font-awesome")
  ]
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```